# Is that possible to get WOEID by using city name as now yahoo! APIs are down

Tags: woe-id

As now yahoo API is down, I can not get the WOEID for a city or country. Is that possible to get WOEID by using the country/city name?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the old dataset (by now pretty outdated) at https://archive.org/search?query=geoplanet